# React Native Android build apk error- ':app:packageRelease'

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create apk for RN project by following the steps from [RN official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html). But I'm getting error:

Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key my-key-alias from store "F:\project\myProject\android\app\my-release-key.keystore": No key with alias 'my-key-alias' found in keystore F:\project\myProject\android\my-release-key.keystore

I did:

1. Created `my-release-key.keystore`
2. Placed it in `myProject\android\app` folder
3. In `C:\Users\Username\.gradle\gradle.properties` (Win): (UPDATE)

   ```
     MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore 
     MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias 
     MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=***** (actual pwd)
     MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=***** (actual pwd)
   ```
4. In `myProject\android\app\build.gradle`, added

   ```
   signingConfigs {
         release {
          if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
             storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
             storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
             keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
             keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
           }
        }
   }
   ```
5. And finally `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` - where error occurs.

I also tried `cd android &&./gradlew assembleRelease` which displays same error

I double checked all the values and files, but no luck. It would be a really great if someone would help

Answer (score 1):

From the error  on the last line. It says that no key alias found in the ..\android\my-release-key.keystore not in the ..\android\app\my-release-key.keystore where you keystore is reside.

> No key with alias 'my-key-alias' found in keystore
>   F:\project\myProject\android\my-release-key.keystore

From [RN](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) site,

> Edit the file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties and add the following
>   (replace ***** with the correct keystore password, alias and key
>   password),

Transfer this code from `C:\Users\Username\.gradle` into `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore 
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias 
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=***** (actual pwd)
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=***** (actual pwd)
```

Comment: Hi, I guess both mean the same. Yet, try that but no luck!
Just to be sure, I ran `vim ~/.gradle/gradle.properties` command from project directory and add did as you suggested.

Comment: Try generate new keystore with new keyalias.. Remove that one.

Comment: already tried that many a times, but same issue..I don't understand what I'm missing

Comment: Also tried with brand new project, brand new keystore but it still throws same error..

Comment: did you find any answer ? I'm having the same problem.